# Airflow 2 - ImportError: cannot import name 'BashOperator' from 'airflow.operators'

Tags: airflow

After upgrading to Airflow 2, I got that error in some DAGs:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BashOperator' from 'airflow.operators'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved by change the import.

- old one (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/base_hook.py)

```
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
```

- the new one that works (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v2-0-stable/airflow/hooks/base.py)

```
from airflow.hooks import BashOperator
```

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue recently. The following worked for me:

```
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
```

Comment: please provide version that you use

Answer (score 4):

As for airflow 2.2 the import should be:

```
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
```

More details can be found in [airflow-v2-2-stable-code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v2-2-stable/airflow/operators/bash.py):

> The following imports are **deprecated** in version 2.2: [deprecated
> message in v2.2 source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v2-2-stable/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py)
>
> ```
> from airflow.operators import BashOperator
> ```

Comment: THAT is what works